# Unix Domain Sockets & NPAPI

Tags: npapi, unix-socket

I am looking for source code or library to expose Unix Domain Sockets to my Google Chrome's extension via NPAPI.

Does anything similar or related already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating something like that generically would be exceptionally dangerous; you could, however, use [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) to create a plugin that would do that and it would be prettye easy.  Make sure, though, that you are very careful with the security model since if you can instantiate it on your page someone else can on their page too, and they can then use it maliciously.

Comment: I will look into FireBreath tonight, thanks. As for the security, the path of the socket will be determined by the native part. That + some extra care on the buffers handling should be enough.